# How to add "add to calender" link in email template

Tags: php, calendar, html-email

i am sending email through php script, and i want to add link named "Add To Calendar" once customer will click that link from their event event will be add to email timetable. it is possible?

I have find this feature working for website, but i want to implement in email. Link: https://www.addevent.com/add-to-calendar-button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In emails, it's not possible to execute javascript due to security so you need to settle with "Add to Calendar" links instead.

Using this tool (Events with optional RSVP) you can create an event. Once you've created the event the "Add to Calendar" links will be generated which you can copy/paste into your newsletter or campaign (you can copy the links into the content editor where you type in your text).

https://www.addevent.com/events